# Complex integration and trigonometry

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-integration

I've got a problem to do something. We consider $\alpha(t) = \sin(5t) +i\sin(4t)$, for $t \in [0;2\pi]$. We consider as well : $f_s(z) = \frac{s^4}{z^4-s^4}$. The first question I struggle with is that I don't even succeed to find the set where $f_s$ is continuous. Actually, I know that it's the case for $s^4 \notin \alpha([0;2\pi])$, but the point is to determine $s \in \mathbb{C}$ which verify this property.

So we know that : $z^4=s^4 \iff \exists t\in [0;2\pi] \; (\sin(5t)+i\sin(4t))^4 = s^4 $, but the fact is that I don't know how to transform $\sin(5t)+i\sin(4t)$... I've tried to use trigonometric identities but without success...

Then, I've to determine $\int_{\alpha} f_s(z)dz$, but at the moment I just want to find out where $f_s$ is continuous.

If someone could help me, thank you very much !

Comment: Huh? F is not continuous where $z^4 - s^4 = 0$. Solve that polynomial and you’ve found all of the poles of $f_s$.

Comment: Since polynomials are continuous, rational functions like $f_s$ are continuous everywhere they are defined. So what you are really after is where $f_s$ is not defined. Technically, you can say that $f_s$ is not continuous at its poles, but only because it isn't defined there, and continuity is a condition on points in the function's domain.